# Is my syntax correct here? C++

Tags: c++, vector, syntax, call, procedure

So I've been writing this program basically all day, working through many iterations and problems and finally after finishing it up I go back to run it and find that the simplest part that I had working at the beginning now no longer functions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;


void Determine_Output (double);

int main()
{
    vector<double> thisVector(10);
    double input=-2;
    int i=1;
    double average = 0.00;
    double highest;
    double lowest;

    cout<<setprecision(3);


    for (unsigned z=0; z<10; z++)
    {
        cout<<"Please enter result \"" <<i<< "\": ";
        cin>> input;

        if ((input <= 100)&&(input >= 0))
            {
                thisVector.push_back(input);
                Determine_Output(thisVector[i]);  //Offending procedure call
                i++;
            }
        else if (input == -1)
            break;
        else
        {
            cout<<"Invalid input, must be between 0 and 100\n";
            z--;
        }

    }



void Determine_Output (double output) {     //Offending procedure
    if (output > 90)
        cout<<"A will be assigned to this result\n";
    else if (output > 70)
        cout<<"B will be assigned to this result\n";
    else if (output > 60)
        cout<<"C will be assigned to this result\n";
    else if (output > 50)
        cout<<"P will be assigned to this result\n";
    else
        cout<<"U will be assigned to this result\n";
}
```

When I first wrote the program, this worked as it should (ie. 99 returning A, 77 returning B, 66 returning C and so on)

Now that I've finished the rest of the code (omitted for space reasons) this section always returns U (input of 50 or lower), no matter what the actual input was.
I've literally been working at this one part for two and a half hours now, and it has me stumped.

Comment: If your syntax were incorrect the compiler would complain.

Comment: Since you are using `double` for the variables, you should use `double` constants, such as 90.0, 70.0, 60.0, 50.0 and 100.0.  Presently, the compiler is converting them for you.

Comment: You've marked the 'offending procedure' but I think you're looking in the wrong place. Check `Determine_Output` by running it with some known values and see what you get.

Comment: Also, in C++, indices start with 0, not 1.

Comment: Is there some reason why you are using doubles rather than ints?  If you don't need floating point semantics, I'd recommend avoiding them, as floating point values mean you have to worry about problems caused by rounding errors.

Comment: Yeah the rest of it requires doubles otherwise I wouldn't be using them.
I changed `thisVector.push_back(input);` to `thisVector[i]=input` and it seems to have fixed the issue assigning the letters, but now an input of -1 produces an error.

Comment: Sorry, thanks @AdamLiss, you're correct it's not syntax. And I was using `i` simply as an incrementing counter to display, I guess I could have just as easily got the result using `z`, but I changed it to initialize `i=0` and used `i+1` in the output line.

Answer (score 7):

Are you sure you want to initialize `i = 1`?  And instead of using indices, why aren't you just using `thisVector.back()`?  Or better yet, just pass `input` to `Determine_Output()`.  You can eliminate the variable `i` entirely, at least in the code you've shown us.

Furthermore, you don't need to declare a size for `thisVector`, since `push_back()` will grow the vector as needed.

Answer (score 2):

```
vector<double> thisVector(10);
```

Creates a vector of 10 doubles, all initialized to 0. So `thisVector[0]`, `thisVector[1]`, …, `thisVector[9]` are all 0.0.

Your test is:

```
thisVector.push_back(input);
Determine_Output(thisVector[i]);
```

where `i` starts as `1`, and is incremented each time. The first time through the loop, `thisVector.push_back(input);` adds `input` to the end of the vector, making it the eleventh element, `thisVector[10]`. But `DetermineOutput` is called with element `thisVector[1]`, which still has the value 0.

The next time through the loop, you add `thisVector[11]` and `i` is now `2` so you check `thisVector[2]`, which is, of course, also 0.0. And so on. Only on the last iteration do you check `thisVector[10]`, which is non-zero (since it is the *first* element you read).

So, simplify:

1. Don't initialize the vector to 10 elements. When you start, you want it to be empty.
2. Get rid of `i`. It's completely unnecessary. Use `thisVector.back()` to reference the element you just `push_back`ed. (Or use `input` directly.)
3. Get rid of `z`. It's also unnecessary. You need to run the loop until `thisVector` has 10 elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate the `else if` structure by reversing the order of the comparisons:

```
void Determine_Output(double output)
{
  char letter = 'U';
  if (output > 50)
    letter = 'P';
  if (output > 60)
    letter = 'C';
  if (output > 70)
    letter = 'B';
  if (output > 90)
    letter = 'A';
  cout << letter << " will be assigned to this result.\n";
}
```

The above structure may be less confusing, although it does overwrite the letter many times.